# How to make object A a parent(keep_transform) of object B via Blender's Python API?

Tags: python, parent

[image]
[image: python blender create parent]
[image: create child keep transform blender3D]

**parent keep transform??**

> objects = bpy.data.objects
>
> a = objects['Cube']
>
> b = objects['Cube.001']
>
> b.parent.**keep_transform** = a

**CODE:**

```
import bpy # sin esta libreria no funcionan los comandos en blender
techos = bpy.context.selected_objects

for i in techos:
    #bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES',radius=100,location = i.location) = o

    empty = bpy.data.objects.new( "empty", None )#crea un empty y lo guarda en una variable
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(empty)#agrega el empty a la escena
    empty.empty_display_size = 3 #da un tamaño al empty
    empty.empty_display_type = 'PLAIN_AXES'#determina la forma del empty
    empty.location = i.location #la locacion del empty es la misma que la del objeto seleccionado


    i.parent = empty#el objeto seleccionado es hijo del empty
    i.matrix_parent_inverse = empty.matrix_world.inverted()    

    #i.parent_set(i,keep_transform = True)
    #i.parent_set()
    print(empty)
```

***I found a solution, putting the object "I" on both sides, however I can't understand it well***
[image: blender keep transform parent]

Comment: **parent keep transform??**

objects = bpy.data.objects
a = objects['Cube']
b = objects['Cube.001']

b.parent.**keep_transform** = a **???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retain the transformation of the child you can do this:

```
 b.parent = a
 b.matrix_parent_inverse = a.matrix_world.inverted()
```

[image]

You need to update depsgraph after creating the empty (matrix_world of the newly created object is updated after updating depsgraph):

```
import bpy # sin esta libreria no funcionan los comandos en blender
techos = bpy.context.selected_objects

for i in techos:
    #bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES',radius=100,location = i.location) = o

    empty = bpy.data.objects.new( "empty", None )#crea un empty y lo guarda en una variable
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(empty)#agrega el empty a la escena
    empty.empty_display_size = 3 #da un tamaño al empty
    empty.empty_display_type = 'PLAIN_AXES'#determina la forma del empty
    empty.location = i.location #la locacion del empty es la misma que la del objeto seleccionado


    # Add this line
    bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().update()


    i.parent = empty#el objeto seleccionado es hijo del empty
    i.matrix_parent_inverse = empty.matrix_world.inverted()    

    #i.parent_set(i,keep_transform = True)
    #i.parent_set()
    print(empty)
```

Comment: It does not work although I can make the relationship the object moves from its place of origin.

Comment: Please see edit. Is it possible for you to share your code?

Comment: there I put the sample code choose some objects from the scene and this script creates an empty which is then the parent of the selected object

Comment: Please see the updated code. You need to add the line: `bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().update()`

Comment: Update the publication with the solution I found or found, but I vote yours too.
If instead of putting empty I put "I" the problem is solved, but in the way you told me too, even if I don't understand it very well, you helped me a lot ... until next time ...

Comment: It's because object `i` has the same location as the `empty` (`empty.location = i.location`). If you transform the empty in any other way, you will need to update the depsgraph. Anyways, glad that you could resolve the problem!